# WordPress custom meta box wont save

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have the following code which adds a custom meta box to wordpress pages but for some reason it wont save the selected option. Any ideas whats wrong ?

Thanks.

```
 // Add Header Select Option MetaBox
function alfie_header_select_meta() {
add_meta_box( 'alfie_header_select_meta', __( 'Header Style', 'alfie' ), 'alfie_header_select_meta_callback', 'page', 'side' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'alfie_header_select_meta' );

function alfie_header_select_meta_callback( $post ) {
$values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
$selected = isset( $values['alfie_selected_header'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['alfie_selected_header'][0] ) : ”;
wp_nonce_field( 'alfie_header_select_meta_nonce', 'alfie_header_select_meta_nonce' );
?>
  <p>
      <select name="alfie_selected_header" id="alfie_selected_header">
          <option value="alfie-header-default" <?php selected( $selected, 'default' ); ?>>Default</option>
          <option value="alfie-header-style-minimal" <?php selected( $selected, 'minimal' ); ?>>Minimal</option>
          <option value="alfie-header-test" <?php selected( $selected, 'test' ); ?>>Just a test option</option>
      </select>
  </p>
<?php
}

function alfie_meta_save( $post_id ) {
$is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
$is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
$is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'alfie_header_select_meta_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'alfie_header_select_meta_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
    return;
}

if( isset( $_POST[ 'alfie_selected_header' ] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'alfie_selected_header', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'alfie_selected_header' ] ) );
}
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'alfie_meta_save' );
```

Comment: Its probably in the autosave / nonce check inside the alfie_meta_save(). Did you see if the code is running after that if block? You should test it out and see.

Comment: Sorry for being dumb but how do i do that ?

Comment: One idea is to save a default meta after the if block and check if it gets added in.

Comment: Use:   update_post_meta( $post_id, 'alfie_selected_header', 'yay' ); just after the if block and see. I'm just telling you a quick and easy method to debug this

Comment: Thanks, i added it but nothing changed, it just goes back to default after save

Comment: On a first glance the problem seems to be with the nonce checking. Just remove !$is_valid_nonce and see if it works

Comment: Tried that but still wont work :(

Comment: Where are you checking this? Check within the database. not the wordpress edit section. If the meta is added in the database and just not showing up on the edit end, its because of a problem with the display code, not the save

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working debugged code.
The post meta was being saved. But it wasnt displaying because of a difference in the string values and how you got the meta. Just use get_post_meta for a single field.

```
 // Add Header Select Option MetaBox
function alfie_header_select_meta() {
add_meta_box( 'alfie_header_select_meta', __( 'Header Style', 'alfie' ), 'alfie_header_select_meta_callback', 'page', 'side' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'alfie_header_select_meta' );

function alfie_header_select_meta_callback( $post ) {
$selected = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'alfie_selected_header',true);
wp_nonce_field( 'alfie_header_select_meta_nonce', 'alfie_header_select_meta_nonce' );
?>
  <p>
      <select name="alfie_selected_header" id="alfie_selected_header">
          <option value="alfie-header-default" <?php selected( $selected, 'alfie-header-default' ); ?>>Default</option>
          <option value="alfie-header-style-minimal" <?php selected( $selected, 'alfie-header-style-minimal' ); ?>>Minimal</option>
          <option value="alfie-header-test" <?php selected( $selected, 'alfie-header-test' ); ?>>Just a test option</option>
      </select>
  </p>
<?php
}

function alfie_meta_save( $post_id ) {
$is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
$is_revision = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id );
$is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ 'alfie_header_select_meta_nonce' ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ 'alfie_header_select_meta_nonce' ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) ) ? 'true' : 'false';

if ( $is_autosave || $is_revision || !$is_valid_nonce ) {
    return;
}

if( isset( $_POST[ 'alfie_selected_header' ] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'alfie_selected_header', sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'alfie_selected_header' ] ) );
}
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'alfie_meta_save' );
```